# How can I install google talk with video call support on CM7.1?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, cyanogenmod, google-talk

I I just installed CM7.1 on my SGS.  To my surprise, the google apps that I installed did not include the version of google talk with video chat.  The ROM I used to have was based on Samsung's stock Android (2.3.5), and did have this version of google talk.

How can I get this version on my phone?

Is it safe to install google talk from a backup created in my previous version onto CM7.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This version of google talk can be downloaded from http://goo-inside.me/gapps/.

The current version is [gapps-gb-20110828-newtalk-signed.zip](http://goo-inside.me/gapps/gapps-gb-20110828-newtalk-signed.zip).

Details can be found in Rootzwiki at http://wiki.rootzwiki.com/index.php/Google_Apps#Google_Talk_with_Video.2FVoice_Chat